# LocalDateTime Serialization with Jackson results in fields being present twice

Tags: serialization, java-8, jackson, jersey

I have a custom serializer class

```
public class LocalDateTimeSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDateTime>{
  @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        // custom code to serialize
        jgen.writeString(newValue);

    }
```

I use it as below on a class variable:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
```

Now, when I serialize this is json, the response datetime is serialized as expected according to the custom logic. All good here.

But there are some cases, when a field is mapped twice, for no apparent reason. The class variable is declared exactly the same to serialize with the custom serializer, but the output would have two fields for the variable. One would be the expected field serialized. The second would be the non-serialized field. Look at the following output:

```
"localDateTime": //as expected,
"localdateTime":{"year":2017,"month":"JUNE","monthValue":6,"dayOfMonth":29,"hour":20,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0,"dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","dayOfYear":180,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}}
```

This is randomly happening for say two fields of a class.

Any idea what could cause this?

**UPDATE:**

I think it was something to do with how the getter/setter for the entity was named as.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime aOldDate;
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime aNewDate;



public LocalDateTime getaOldDate() {
    return aOldDate;
}
public void setaOldDate(LocalDateTime aOldDate) {
    this.aOldDate= aOldDate;
}

public LocalDateTime getANewDate() {
    return aNewDate;
}
public void setANewDate(LocalDateTime aNewDate) {
    this.aNewDate= aNewDate;
}
```

If I try serializing this, the aNewDate field would be present twice in the json, and the aOldDate would be present once. It is probably because the 'A' is capital in the getter/setter for aNewDate, and this causes some problems. Not entirely sure what happens but relates to section 8.8 in this document: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf

Comment: It probably doesn't have anything to do with your custom serializer. My guess is that you have two properties/fields differing only by their case. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Also, you're reinventing the wheel: Jackson has native support for LocalDateTime serialization as a string. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

Comment: @JBNizet: Please look at my update. That fixes it. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Yes. Your getter doesn't respect the (weird) specification for a property named like that. Let your IDE generate the getter/setter for you, and you'll see that it generates `getaNewDate`, and not `getANewDate`. Why don't you name the properties `newDate` and `oldDate`. This would be more readable and logical, and you wouldn't have this weirdly named getter.

Comment: I agree completely. When I generated these with the IDE, they were generated using a lowercase "a". And that's what I would have done. Also my variable name wouldn't be like this. But this is project at work and this code belongs to someone else, I was doing the serialization for this and found this. Now gonna tell them to read up on naming your variables properly!